# Trying to create a dataframe from a list of tuples, and a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As the title states I'm tyring to create a df using a list of tuples and a tuple.

So what I currently have is

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
b = ('A', 'B')
d = dict(zip(b,a))
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

and my result is:

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Where as I want something like:

```
   0  1
0  A  1,2,3
1  B  4,5,6
```

Any and help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you going to do with that DataFrame? Using that organization, with a complex object in each cell, can greatly complicate later manipulations

Comment: Just want to use the df.to_html functionality that's all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
d1 = {k: ','.join([*map(str,v)]) for k,v in d.items()}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index').reset_index()
```

Comment: @mike_gundy123 we convert values for each key as string and join them using a comma, then create the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I will do `explode`

```
s=pd.Series(d).explode().astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
Out[165]: 
A    1,2,3
B    4,5,6
dtype: object
```